# How to check data is loaded in table or Not using Angular js

Tags: angularjs

I need to check whether data is loaded or not in the Table ?

Based on this some decision ,  i need to perform some operation on it,

**Only Angular js solution please.**

**html**

```
<table ng-model='xxxx'>
   <tr ng-repeat="x in obj" ng-bind='x.name'>---</tr>
<table>
```

**Angular snippet:**

```
$scope.$watch('xxxx', function (val) {
   console.log(val);
   if (val !== undefined) {
              collectData();
     }
   });
```

i was trying to place one ng-model and finding  its value in $watch and find the table is ready for operation or not ...!!!

but it's not working , ng-model ='xxxx' is giving undefined always.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: The Question is how to check Weather data in the Table is loaded or not ?

Comment: Please consider adding a comment when voting down so that the question can be improved. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can execute controller after data loads like this:

```
$routeProvider.when({
    url: '/',
    controller: 'myCtrl',
    templateUrl: 'myTemplate.html',
    resolve: {
        data: function(mySrvc){
            return mySrvc.getData().$promise;
        }
    }
});

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, data){
    // data is already loaded
    $scope.data = data;
});
```

Comment: @PraveenPrakashDSouza sorry, don't understand what you ask. In my case, data parameter will already contain information when executing controller, controller loads after promise is resolved

Comment: The Question is how to check Wether data in the Table is loaded or not ? but how this approch will make sure that domElement has been completly loaded...???

Answer (score 0):

You have put `ngModel` on a table tag which is incorrect. `ngModel` works only on a user input element:

- input
- text
- checkbox
- radio
- number
- email
- url
- date
- dateTimeLocal
- time
- month
- week
- select
- textarea

See docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel

Comment: I agree on your point , But i was expecting of solution for above question ,,

Comment: Your syntax is incorrect. `ngModel` doesn't work for table. Try `ngModel` on some input, that is the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a misunderstanding of when ng-model is used. ng-model is used to bind form controls to data in the $scope. For example, you can bind a input, text, checkbox, radio, number, email, url, date, dateTimeLocal, time, month, week, select, or textarea control to the $scope. It doesn't have anything to do with tables.

You could make an all new directive which would bind to a table, but there is no point in doing that because there are already means in AngularJS to render tables and other read-only data structures in the DOM.

For example, you can use ng-repeat:

```
<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="state in states">
    <td>{{ state.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ state.population }}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

But ng-model is usually used in those cases where there is a control and the user will be entering in data which will then automatically update the $scope variable bound to the control.

Comment: i Agree on your point.When nothing works , i m trying these kind of tricks.